# How to copy all non-empty cells and paste them in the next available cell in a different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy values from Sheet 1, "Delivery Docket". The cells I want to copy will be from A18:A160, all not-empty cells.

The next step is to paste the values from the non empty cells onto Sheet2 "Shipping register" which will start from cell A2 and go down if the cell is not empty. I had previously asked a friend to make this for me and I vaguely remember him adding a loop and + 1 function, since every time that a cell has a value the macro would have to move to the next cell.

[image]

Comment: Please, be more specific (read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I'm really having trouble explaining it but I will try my best. Please be patient with me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub copyNon_EmptyCells()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim vals() As String, valCount As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer, r As Integer

    Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = Sheets(2)

    ' set last row variable
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For r = 18 To lastRow
        If (Not ws1.Cells(r, 1) = vbNullString) Then
            ReDim Preserve vals(valCount)
            vals(valCount) = ws1.Cells(r, 1)
            valCount = valCount + 1
        End If
    Next r

    For r = 0 To valCount - 1
        ws2.Cells(r + 2, 2) = vals(r)
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm really having trouble explaining it but I will try my best. Please be patient with me. What I want to accomplish is to copy values from sheet1 "Delivery Docket" the cells i want to copy will be from A18:A160 all not empty cells, the next step is to paste the values from the non empty cells onto Sheet2 "Shipping register" which will start from cell A2 and go down if the cell is not empty. I had previously asked a friend to make this for me and I vaguely remember him adding a loop and + 1 function, since everytime that a cell has a value the macro would have to move to the next cell

Comment: The code above does exactly what you have asked, except that you originally stated that you wanted the values to start on:"sheet2 B2 going down"

Comment: To refer to sheets by name, use Set ws1 = Sheets("Delivery Docket"), etc. The For Loop mitigates the need for a "+1" (which would be needed in a Do Loop) as the "Next" command increments the counter value by one (or a specified value if you use a Step argument).